# Typescript : reuse both of for .. of and for .. in at same level

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to reuse "**for .. of** " to loop over an array of objects , 
at same time i want to get the index inn each time (with : **for.. in**).

so that i can change a specifc object with another accortding to its index.

My purpose is to loop over a list , find a specifc object by its name attribute , and change it with another object.

```
updateObjectInList(list, newObject) {

    for(let item of list , let index in list ){
      if (item.name=== newObject.name){
        list[index] = newObject
      }
    }

}
```

Of course this stament " `let item of list , let index in list`  " is not working

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: Use `.forEach()`, which gives you both the value and the index.

Comment: I wouldn't want `for..in` for an array.  You can use `list.forEach((item, index)=>{...})` if you want

Comment: Also, you could just use [`list.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) if your runtime supports it

Comment: It's not entirely clear how you want this to work. Seems like it would be easier to do `list[list.findIndex(item => item.name === newObject.name)] = newObject`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take an iterator of the entries of the array and get index and value at the same time.

```js
var array = [33, 22, 11];

for (const [index, value] of array.entries()) {
    console.log(index, value);
}
```